# c# streamWriter WriteLineAsync without await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, async-await

I want to write to `StreamWriter` line `async` but I don't want to await on this.

```
for(int i= 0 ;i<1000;i++)
{
  sw.WriteLineAsync(i.ToString());
}
```

But i got an error that i invoke to `WriteLineAsync` in same time.

1. What can I do to fix that?
2. I want to close this `StreamWriter` after this loop.

How can I verify that I now close without to write all data on `StreamWriter`, Or when I close the stream all the data that sent with `WriteLineAsync` will be write before the stream close?

Comment: If using the async methods you need to await them. That is the only way to properly write and then close the stream. Otherwise just use the WriteLine and avoid async

Comment: @Nkosi why if you want WriteLineAsync i must use awit? I don't want to wait for the result and i don't want to use WriteLine because I don't want to wait until the line will be write

Comment: You will corrupt the file if you call multiple  `WriteLineAync` without `await` You seem to not understand the purpose of async/await. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What is your real intention? Do you want the value to be written or not? If you want work ahead while your value is written, your question isn’t about async but about multithreading.

Comment: What is the point in using asynch methods if you don't want to await them? Just go for a plain `sw.WriteLine`.

Comment: on WriteLine my thread will wait until the line will be write I dont want to wait for that, I want to continue to next loop and the line will be write async

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write the lines using async, you should use `await`. Because, the file might be corrupted and you might encounter with possible stream errors like *"the stream is already in use"*. In short, you should synchronize the write action.
So, I provided an example;

```
    private async Task WriteToFileAsAsync()
    {
        string file = @"sample.txt";
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(i.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, you can close and dispose the `StreamWriter` within `using` blocks.

**EDIT**

If you want to perform write action in separately from main thread, don't use async methods and just create a seperate `Task` and assign it an another thread.

```
    private void WriteToFile()
    {
        string file = @"sample.txt";
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then call like this;

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(WriteToFile);
```

Comment: why if you want WriteLineAsync i must use awit? I don't want to wait for the result and i don't want to use WriteLine because I don't want to wait until the  line will be write

Comment: The main thread isn't blocked with await. The thread continues execution from the caller method. This is the only right way to use await.

Comment: I know the thread back to caller, but I want the my thread will continue to next loop immediately , not wait to finish writeLine

Comment: Since you are providing full example, worth using `FileOptions.Asynchronous`, because otherwise async operations on that filestream are not "truly" async.

Comment: @Evk, you are right. Actually, I figured out that the OP doesn't desire async or he supposed async works in a different background thread. So, he just desire to perform write action in seperated thread. It is not async.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular context there are two main issues in doing what you would like to do.
Technically speaking, if you call an async method, you need to `await` for it sooner or later, hence you can collect the task, and `await` for it later on. However, the `WriteLineAsync` method is **not atomic**, therefore calling it and performing other operations on the stream can corrupt the stream itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to await, then don't call the Async method..

If you want to close a stream after using, use `using` with it.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("temp.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you want it to be asynchronous, then you have to call the Async version, otherwise it will corrupt the file.

Comment: why if you want WriteLineAsync i must use awit? I don't want to wait for the result and i don't want to use WriteLine because I don't want to wait until the line will be write

Comment: You either use WriteLine normally, or await WriteLineAsync. If you don't, it will corrupt the file.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. If you don't want to wait for the write opearation to be done, why not await it? It is why it exists..

Comment: I want the my thread will continue to next loop immediately , not wait to finish writeLine

Comment: And what do you think would happen if your for loop continues before the current writeline finishes? It would write into the current line.